# jQuery ajax call and a 404 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Im trying to make a jquery ajax call but im getting a **404 error**.

This is my code

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/wp-content/themes/mytheme/ajax_functions.php",
    data: "sec=load_team&year=2010",
    success: function(msg){
        jQuery("#update_div").html(msg);
    },
    error: function(msg){
        console.log(msg.statusText);
    }
});
```

The website is not visible for everyone, Ive changed my hosts file:

xx.xx.xx.xx www.mydomain.com

Chrome inspector says:

> POST
>   http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/ajax_functions.php
>   404 (Not Found)

But If I copy/paste that URL in the address bar, it exists...

Comment: May be `ajax_functions.php` Creates 404 error on having `POST` request. When you load it on browser its just a GET request.

Comment: Change the type to "GET" and see if it works, if it does, check on the server why it decline to receive POSTs requests

Answer (score 4):

In ajax_functions.php I had:

> require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');

I changed it by:

> require('../../../wp-load.php');

Now its working fine, but i dont know why doesnt work with wp-blog-header because its in the same folder as wp-load.php

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the full url "http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/ajax_functions.php " in the url: parameter instead of relying on the module/browser to determine the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `ajax_functions.php` page on the same domain as the page hosting the Javascript?

You may be getting blocked because of [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) in which case you'll need to specify a `dataType` of `jsonp` in your AJAX options.

Otherwise make sure the URL actually handles POST requests.  If you need help with this, show your PHP code for that page.